# How to create array from images in a div

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

```
<div id="w01">
<img src=g_bur/01.jpg alt='img'>
<img src=g_bur/02.jpg alt='img'>
<img src=g_bur/03.jpg alt='img'>
</div>
```

I need an array of elements made from this images

js

```
var arr = [];
$("#w01 > img").each(function(){
    arr.push($(this));
}
alert (arr) //error
```

Error: `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`toArray()`](https://api.jquery.com/toArray/):

```
var arr = $("#w01 > img").toArray();
```

... or alter your original code like so:

```
var arr = [];
$("#w01 > img").each(function(){
    arr.push(this); // this instead of $(this) so you only get the <img>
}); // you were missing a closing paren
alert(arr);
```

Answer (score 1):

You forgot to put ')'

Here:

```
$("#w01 > img").each(function(){
    arr.push($(this));
}); //<<<<
```